# How to generate tokens for mail verify or forgot password without FusionAuth sending mail?

Tags: fusionauth

Until yesterday I was using the default mechanism of sending mails like "verify mail" or "forgot password mail". These mails have specials tokens included inside the mail. Both of these endpoint also returns tokens in the response body.
I am now changing the way of sending mails in my application and I want to do it with a separate service. So to activate my users or change their password I need these tokens, but I dont want FusionAuth to send emails. When disabling "verify mails" or "forgot password", calling these endpoints results in a 403. Is there a way to get this tokens without starting the process of sending a mail by FusionAuth ?
The workaround is to add a fake host to the mail config. But it isn't the best idea since I see then an error in logs when generating tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/api/user/forgot-password` API and set `sendForgotPasswordEmail` to `false`.

In the [Forgot Password API](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users#start-forgot-password-workflow) it is the second example :

> Start the forgot password workflow using an API key

This will create you a token and will not send the email. You can then build the link yourself and send the email through an external service.

Comment: I find out how to do it with the forgot password flow, but i did not with the verification process. Could help with this ?
When registering a new user, setting the skipVerification to true, allows the user to login just after registering. But when is it set to fase, the email i always sent. I've tried with setting `verified` and `active` in userregistration to false manually, but it didnt do the trick.

Comment: The Email verification works similarly. You can call `[PUT]` on the Verify Email API to generate a note code and set `sendVerifyEmail` to `false`.  https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users#resend-verification-email An un-verified user can still login, if you want to limit privileges until verified you can do that by looking at the `verified` attribute on the use or registration.

Comment: Ok, the problem is kind of weird.
When starting FusionAuth for the first time and configuring it, without setting anything in the email settings (disabled), the calls for getting tokens for verifying mail are not comming (status 200, verificationId = null). Then I configure the email settings with random values, and enable verify email, then save all and then again Disable all email settings. Then these calls return the desired tokens.
FusionAuth version 1.3.1